# login with oracle database

Tags: android, oracle, authentication, oracle11g, database-connection

Username and password are already in oracle database.

```
username="abc"
password="123"
```

login.

Now i need connection with oracle.Then i want to  a **php** script that will take this username and password..and in response it should give me result whether username and password exists in oracle database or not..

i can do the stuff with MySQL but don't know how to interact with oracle from android.

```
<?php
define ('DB_HOST','localhost');

define ('DB_USER','root');

define ('DB_PASS','');

define ('DB_NAME','schools');

$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())

  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else{
      //echo"successfully connect";
  }
?>
```

In mysql it can be done like this.
Basically i want clear steps to do the same with oracle.

Shall be very thankful to experts!`

Comment: Unclear, do you want to connect from php or java.

Comment: Thanks..i want to use php to connect to oracle..

Comment: I got the solution..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I found the solution..Php code for connecting to oracle..also login code.

```html
// Create connection to Oracle
$conn = oci_connect("system", "password", "//localhost/xe");
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
   print "Connected to Oracle!";
}

// Close the Oracle connection
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

```html
Login:
       <?php

// Create connection to Oracle
$conn = oci_connect("system", "password!", "//localhost/XE");
$username= $_POST['user_name'];
$userpass= $_POST['user_pass'];

$query = "select * from TABLE1 where STUDENT_NAME = '$username' AND STUDENT_PASS='$userpass' ";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stid);

  $row = oci_fetch_array($stid); 
   if (oci_num_rows ($stid) >=1){
    echo "1";
   }
   else{
    echo "0";
   }



?>
```